# Why am I unable to create an instance of an object using IL Generation in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit, dynamicmethod

I have the following class:

```
private sealed class Person
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Age { get; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

And the following method to dynamically create an instance of a `ConstructorInfo`:

```
public static Func<object[], T> GetBuilder<T>(ConstructorInfo constructor)
{
    var type = constructor.ReflectedType;    
    var ctorParams = constructor.GetParameters();

    var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("Create_" + constructor.Name, type, new[] { typeof(object[]) }, type, true);
    var ilGen = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();

    /*
     * Cast each argument of the input object array to the appropriate type
     * The order of objects should match the order set by the Ctor
     * It is also assumed the length of object array args is same length as Ctor args. 
     * Exceptions for the delegate that mean the above weren't satisfied: 
     * InvalidCastException, IndexOutOfRangeException
     */
    for (var i = 0; i < ctorParams.Length; i++)
    {
        // Push Object array
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

        // Push the index to access
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);

        // Push the element at the previously loaded index
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);

        // Cast the object to the appropriate Ctor Parameter Type
        var paramType = ctorParams[i].ParameterType;
        ilGen.Emit(paramType.IsValueType ? OpCodes.Box : OpCodes.Castclass, paramType);
    }

    // Call the Ctor, all values on the stack are passed to the Ctor
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, constructor);
    // Return the new object
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    // Create delegate from our IL, cast and return
    return (Func<object[], T>)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object[], T>));
}
```

I then use the method to create two instances of this class one for each of the constructors:

```
var ctorOne = typeof(Person).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)[0];
var instanceBuilderOne = GetBuilder<Person>(publicCtor[0]);
var instanceOne = instanceBuilderOne(new object[] { "Foo"});
instanceOne.Name.Dump(); // is "Foo"

var ctorTwo = typeof(Person).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)[1];
var instanceBuilderTwo = GetBuilder<Person>(publicCtor[1]);
var instanceTwo = instanceBuilderTwo(new object[] { "Bar", 1});
instanceTwo.Name.Dump(); // is "Bar"
instanceTwo.Age.Dump(); // is 43603896
```

However for the `instanceTwo` instead of getting **1** I am getting **43603896**.

Hitting the breakpoint in the related constructor does indeed show *43603896* being passed to the instance but I cannot figure out why!?

Comment: are `publicCtor[0]` and `publicCtor[1]` typos?

Comment: No, one is the 1st constructor which gets one param of type `string`, the other is the 2nd which gets one param of type `string` and another of type `int`.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Unbox` instead of `Box`? The value was already boxed when pushed into `object[]`. Now you want to get it back as `int`. What you're getting looks like a random number which might represent a *location* of the value you're boxing.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, no that's not it, changing it didn't make a difference. The value is indeed random though.

Comment: This question really serves to remind me how little I still know about C# ... Can `GetBuilder()` differentiate 1 as an `int` versus some other type? Does this still happen if you change 1 to something like 42?

Comment: @levelonehuman, The issue is independent of the value, however, if I change the constructor param from `int` to `string` it successfully gets the 2nd param but somehow it seems to me the **ValueType** is being messed up during `boxing`/`unboxing`.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750585/value-type-conversion-in-dynamically-generated-il) can help.

Comment: You have to replace your OpCodes.Box with OpCodes.Unbox_Any. Actually you can replace your ValueType check with "ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, paramType);", because it will work for reference types too.

Comment: @Evk That was it! What's the difference though between `Unbox` and `Unbox_Any`? Feel free to add it as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `OpCodes.Box` is obviously wrong here, because you want to unbox int from object, not box it.

Now what `OpCodes.Unbox` does is it unboxes value and pushes *reference* to unboxed value to the stack. That reference is what you see instead of "1". If you want to use `OpCodes.Unbox`, correct way is this:

```
if (paramType.IsValueType) {
     ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox, paramType);
     ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldobj, paramType);
}
else {
      ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, paramType);
}
```

But easier to just use `OpCodes.Unbox_Any` which will basically do the same, but in one line:

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, paramType);
```